# Control volume using right click and wheel, like volumemouse and volume2

Tags: volume-control, mouse-wheel

Ubuntu 18.04:

Coming from Windows, I had these 2 apps I could use (volumemouse, volume2) to control the volume using this gesture:
right click + wheel

is there anything like that for ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: what is your OS?? ubuntu 18.04 19.04 16.04 etc??

Comment: @PRATAP 18.04, I updated the question

Comment: I did not try yet.. but seems possible with `xbindkeys`.. will try in a while.. meanwhile you can study `man xbindkeys`